# Django: Do I have to check if variable is not NULL in clean() method?

Tags: python, django

In my `models.py` I have a `clean()` method that should do some validation affecting multiple fields of a model.

However, I noticed that I have to check for every field that I need in the clean() method if it's not null. Even if the fields have `blank=False` the clean() method is run although not all required fields have been filled.

So here can you find my clean() method now:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.fieldA and self.fieldB:
        if self.fieldA > self.fieldB:
            raise ValidationError("Some text")

    if self.fieldC and self.fieldA:
        if self.fieldC > self.fieldA:
            raise ValidationError("Some other text")

    if self.fieldD and self.fieldB:
        if self.fieldD < self.fieldB:
            raise ValidationError("Some other text")
```

**My question:**

Is that really the way to go, am I doing it the right way? Because in the docs I could not find all those checks if the fields are available. However, in my experience it showed they are.

I'd like to have some input/explanation from experienced Django devs.

Comment: Is your `clean()` method above being called as part of validating a ModelForm object, or are you calling it directly?

Comment: The clean() method is called automatically by Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `clean` method looks ok. You can't assume that values are set in the `clean` method, so your checks are necessary.

If a field has `blank=False`, then there will be an error raised in the `clean_fields` method. However the validation doesn't stop at that point. The `full_clean` method will call the `clean()` method first, so it's up to you to add checks before you do `if self.fieldA > self.fieldB:` (which will raise a `TypeError` for `None` in Python 3).

Answer (score -2):

Django docs don't make this particularly clear, but the `clean()` method on a model is **only** called when processing data with a ModelForm, or when you copy the approach that a ModelForm takes for validation: i.e., following the three steps listed here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Edit: As in, if you call `clean()` by itself, you will likely find null values as you did, since `Model.clean_fields()` hasn't been run yet.

Comment: I did not call clean() by myself. And Model.clean_fields() is called before Model.clean(), that's at least what the docs say:
"This method calls Model.clean_fields(), Model.clean(), and Model.validate_unique() (if validate_unique is True), in that order ..."